# How to debug in WebStorm Gulp tasks written in TypeScript from (gulpfile.ts)

Tags: typescript, gulp, webstorm

Currently it looks very easy to debug Gulp tasks in WebStorm when they are written in JavaScript. You just right click on the gulp task from the Gulp Tasks Window and select debug and voila :). Now with TypeScript used frequently around and after installing https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node you can write your Gulp tasks using TypeScript and you will be able to also create `gulpfile.ts` instead of `gulpfile.js`.

Running Gulp tasks written with TypeScript is the same as before `gulp my.task` and actual code of your task will be inside `my.task.ts`. What will happen is that this `ts-node` module will do some magic probably compile in memory the `gulpfile.ts` and all registered there tasks, then it will provide them some how to the real `Gulp` node module.

**My question is** how can I add break point to this Gulp `*.ts` files and debug them via WebStorm?

Here is what happens if I try to debug a gulp task written with TypeScript:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 2016.2.3\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" --debug-brk=64720 --expose_debug_as=v8debug E:\XXXXXXXX\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js --color --gulpfile E:\XXXXXXXX\gulpfile.ts build.js.dev
Debugger listening on [::]:64720
[17:43:13] Requiring external module ts-node/register

Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)
```

You can find a project which use TypeScript to write Gulp tasks here: https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed